# create zip file with folder structure with c#

Tags: c#, zip, directory

i have a folder structure and files in those folders.i have to zip all those files with folder structure. 
i found examples which only zip a file not all folder structure. i am working on VS 2008. please suggest me the way to zip files with folder structure with c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i dont have to create folders first. it creates folder automatically when i specify files with folder name. and it works with both the links provided. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) ?

You can use it to [zip a folder](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/).